# Ocultar una columna de una Tabla de Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Estoy tratando de ocultar esta columna en una mat-table hecho con angular material

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Cedula">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Recibo Inicial </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let solicitud">
      <ng-container *ngIf="solicitud?.AdjReciboInicial == true; then thenBlock; else elseBlock"></ng-container>

      <ng-template #thenBlock>
        <span><i class="fas fa-check-circle text-success"></i></span>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template #elseBlock>
        <span><i class="fas fa-times-circle text-danger"></i></span>
      </ng-template>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Estoy colocando un ng If en el container de la siguiente manera:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Cedula" *ngIf="mostrarColumna">
```

Y seteando la propiedad como false, pero al momento de correr el codigo me muestra este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tambien puedes usar [`splice()` para agregar y quitar columnas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Por ejemplo, el siguiente código crea un array con 3 elementos ("gender", "age" y "etc") y luego inserta 2 elementos ("name" y "lastname") al principio del array:

```
myDisplayedColumns = ['gender', 'age', 'etc'];
myDisplayedColumns.splice(0,0,'name','lastname')
```

Comment: Yo creo que tu respuesta está casi bien. Yo le agregaría más información sobre splice y un link a algún sitio para obtener más información sobre esa función junto a una cita de lo más importante de dicha pagina en la respuesta por si se cae el link. Recuerda que hacer estos cambios hará que tu respuesta sea de mejor calidad, sea mejor recibida y el autor de la pregunta y otros que vean tu respuesta en el futuro podrían aprender algo nuevo. O al menos creo que con estos cambios sería mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr lo que quieres la solución a la que llegué yo fue filtrar el arreglo con columnas a mostrar, por ejemplo:

```
displayedColumns = [];

if (mostrarColumna) {
    displayedColumns.push('Cedula')
}
```

en el html mantienes el ng-container para Cedula ya que el que hace que una columna se muestre o no es el arreglo de columnas a desplegarse no lo que esta en el html

Comment: Muchas Gracias, esta fue la solucion.

Comment: @NatanaelMedina si esta respuesta te sirvió como solución, por favor, márcala como aceptada. Lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers) y completa el [tour] para más información (y así ganarás tu primera medalla).